# cs50 - pset 2 - substitution program

Tags: c, encryption, input, cs50, substitution

**I was doing the cs50 pset 2 - substitution, where we have to encrypt the plaintext using the key given by the user in the command line, but the following code isn't prompting for an input. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int check(int c, string key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int checkR = check(argc, argv[1]);
    if(checkR == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        string key = argv[1];
        string ptext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        int len = strlen(ptext);
        char ctext[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if(isupper(ptext[i]))
                ctext[i] = toupper(key[(int)ptext[i] - 65]);
            else if(islower(ptext[i]))
                ctext[i] = tolower(key[(int)ptext[i] - 97]);
            else
                ctext[i] = ptext[i];
        }
        printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ctext);
        return 0;
    }
}

int check(int c, string key)
{
    int keyL = strlen(key);
    
    if(c != 2)
        return 1;
        
    else if(keyL != 26)
        return 1;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < keyL - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < keyL; j++)
        {
            if(key[i] == key[j])
                return 1;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer for the question

In the `check` function, you initialized the inner loop as `int j = i`.
Therefore, in the first iteration, `key[i] == key[j]` will be always true.
Then, `1` is returned from `check` and it prevents `main` function from printing the prompt.
The initialization should be `int j = i + 1`.

## Other mistakes

Firstly, it is bad to do `int keyL = strlen(key);` before checking `c` because `key` (`argv[1]`) may be `NULL` when `c` (`argc`) is less than `2`.

Secondly, `printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ctext);` in this code will invoke *undefined behavior* because what is stored in `ctext` is not NUL-terminated.
`char ctext[len];` should be `char ctext[len+1];` and `ctext[len]='\0';` should be added before `printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ctext);`.